# ReactJs Build is failing "@popperjs/core"

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm getting following error while building reactjs app.

```
web/node_modules/@popperjs/core: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: patch-package
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/web/node_modules/@popperjs/core
Output:
/bin/sh: 1: patch-package: not found
```

It's failing at command "yarn install"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening due to a new release. It has been fixed here https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core/issues/1176